# setOnSeekBarChangeListener NullPointerException android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, seekbar

```
class PlayAreaView extends View{  
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "PlayAreaView";
    private SeekBar sizeSlider;
    private int xMin = 0;
    private int xMax;
    private int yMin = 0;
    private int yMax;

    private Rect rect;
    private GestureDetector gestures;
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    private int side = 50;

    public PlayAreaView(Context context){
        super(context);
        rect = new Rect(0,0,side,side);
        p.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        GestureListener listener = new GestureListener(this);
        gestures = new GestureDetector(listener);
        sizeSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);
        //sizeSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener);
    }
```

I am new to developing on Android and am having trouble figuring out what is wrong here. I am getting a NullPointerException at the commented out line. I believe it is because I am asking to findViewById in a class that is not the main activity. If this is indeed the problem how can I access UI elements from this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have set up, findViewById(R.id.seek) will search for a subview with ID equal to R.id.seek **within PlayAreaView**, which does not exist since you seem to have the SeekBar in your main layout.

If you must access The SeekBar from within this view, pass in a reference to it while instantiating it, e.g., in the main activity

```
SeekBar sizeSlider = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
PlayAreaView areaView = new PlayAreaView(this, sizeSlider);
```

and in PlayAreaView,

```
SeekBar sizeSlider;

public PlayAreaView(Context context, SeekBar seekBar) {
  super(context);
  sizeSlider = seekBar;
  ...
  seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(...);
}
```

then, the SeekBar instance can be accessed through the instance variable sizeSlider from PlaAreaView.